# Double return in python class method

Tags: python, return-value

When I call the following method, two returns are executed and I can't figure out why.

```
def Build(self, name = None):
    if self.buildData:
        try:
            installData = self.buildData.Build(name)
            return BuildResult(True, installData)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        Log("Application has no <build> data")
    return BuildResult(False, None)
```

What happens is this:

1. The method is called with a valid string, say "abc"
2. self.buildData.Build(name) is called and BuildResult(True, installData) constructor is run
3. The last return-statement is also executed

Comment: Please fix your "except:" clause to print the exception that's actually raised there.  That will help you see what's happening.

Comment: What is `self.buildData`? Are you sure it isn't a reference back to the parent class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I guess that BuildResult() fails, exception is passed and you go into second return. You can easy test it just by adding some debug print in except - never make exceptions silent :)

Answer (score 1):

When `return BuildResult(True, installData)`  is executed `BuildResult(True, installData`) is evaluated first. My guess is, this function raises an exception which is caught and `pass`ed. After that `return BuildResult(False, None)` is executed.

You should see what exception is raised and handle it properly.

I would rewrite the function as follows:

```
def Build(self, name = None):
    if self.buildData:
        try:
            installData = self.buildData.Build(name)
        except: # TODO: catch only expected exception
            pass
        return BuildResult(True, installData)
    else:
        Log("Application has no <build> data")
    return BuildResult(False, None)
```